# Webview Universal Link Load URL

Tags: ios

so having a bit of trouble getting a certain use case to work.

I created an app for iOS that uses WebView. Everything works great, and I was able to configure Universal Links successfully. It prompts to open in app as it should.

The problem is the URL path i have set to trigger the app, does not pass through to the app.

So the app opens, but it only opens on the home page if it hasn't been opened yet, or it opens to the last location it was at.

I believe it has to do with the fact its webview and it needs to load the same URL that triggered it so it can go to the path.

Example: The URL is https://testapp.com/path

But in the WebView app, it just goes to https://testapp.com if it hasn't been opened (Home Page)

Or to https://testapp.com/lastlocation if it was opened and thats the last spot it was in.

Ive tried setting App Delegate with the below with no luck.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) ->
                        Bool {
        guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else{return false}
        guard let component = URLComponents(string: url.absoluteString) else {return false}
        

        return true
    }
```

Comment: WKWebView doesn't attempt to follow universal links. You would need to add a navigation delegate and catch universal links in `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:)` then handle them yourself.

Comment: You sir are a life saver! This was the exact direction I needed to get this fixed! Will post my answer based on this for any last suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [rudedog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212649/rudedog) for this. Below is what I was able to get working based on this suggestion.

Added the below to App Delegate that triggers the Universal Link

**App Delegate**

```
var universalLinkURL: String = ""

func application(_: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler _: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
        print(universalLinkURL)
        return false
    }
    let universalURL = url.absoluteString
    universalLinkURL = universalURL
    print(universalURL, universalLinkURL)
    return true
}
```

Then in the View Controller I added these pieces of code within both viewDidLoad for initial launch of app, and under appDidBecomeActive, so if app is open it processes the universal link properly.

**func viewDidLoad** and **func appDidBecomeActive**

```
    //Get the url from AppDelegate here
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let universalurl = appDelegate.universalLinkURL
    
    if (!universalurl.isEmpty)
    {
        let urluniversal = URL(string: universalurl)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: urluniversal!))
    }
```

And lastly in order to avoid the variable always triggering a load if you close app, put it in background, etc. I am clearing the variable within the below func's inside **App Delegate**

**applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, and applicationWillEnterForeground**

```
universalLinkURL = ""
```

Hopefully this helps anyone if they come across a similar scenario!